# Table design uploading multiple files (like yahoo mail)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Like what we do in sending email in yahoo, Now in my aspx I want to make a page it's name is "draft" and in this page there is one subject field (txtsubject") and upload control with upload button for attaching multiple files and one another button for save/send in database table, now I do not know how it should be my design table.

I read some article from net about how to upload multiple files and in all of them there is one table like below design

```
Fileid
File name
Content type
```

Comment: what you actually want to do?? you want table design or page design which have all this functionalities...

Comment: page design which have all this functionalities